# Envio de formulário via AJAX, method PUT

Tags: laravel, ajax, restful

**Problema:**

Estou tentando enviar um formulario com ajax via PUT, mas ele está retornando a seguinte mensagem no console do chrome:

```
PUT http://intranet.dev/%7B%7B%20URL::to('upload/'.Auth::user()-%3Eid)%20%7D%7D 403 (Forbidden)
```

**Script:**

Segue o script em AJAX:

```
    $('#file').click();
    $('#file').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
            },
            type: 'PUT',
            url: "{{ URL::to('upload/'.Auth::user()->id) }}",
            data: 'file='+$('#file').val(),
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function(data){
                "{{ Redirect::to('/')->with('success', 'Alterado com sucesso !') }}";
            },
            error: function(){
                "{{ Redirect::to('/')->with('error', 'Erro no Ajax !') }}";
            }
        });
    });
```

**Função:**

Esse código faz com que ao selecionar um arquivo para *upload*, ele acione o meu *controller restful - PUT*.

Comment: fiz o teste com POST e retornou o mesmo erro

Comment: ops, arquivos .js não aceitam o template blade. Estou tentando alguma solução e ja posto aqui

Comment: Se tiver uma pasta em 'public/imagens' por exemplo com o mesmo nome da pasta da view, não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUÇÃO:**

O problema estava no blade do Laravel, minha pagina em ajax que estava com o nome **script.js**, foi renomeado para **script.blade.php** e após isso utilizei o **@include('script')** na minha pagina principal e passou a reconhecer o comando blade.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o problema é você estar usando o `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'` ou de alguma outra forma informando o servidor que a requisição vem de um formulário. De acordo com [esta resposta no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers) as operações GET, POST, PUT e DELETE em Ajax são suportadas pelos principais navegadores (inclusive o [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546998/2241463)) porém formulários HTML/XHTML somente suportam requisições GET e POST.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o problema esteja nessa linha:

```
url: "{{ URL::to('upload/'.Auth::user()->id) }}",
```

Se você observar a mensagem de erro

```
PUT http://intranet.dev/%7B%7B%20URL::to('upload/'.Auth::user()-%3Eid)%20%7D%7D 403 (Forbidden)
```

vai ver que, o que deveria ser uma URL válida, na verdade é uma peça de código não interpretado. Por isso o erro 403. Por algum motivo, o Laravel não está convertendo o seu código em uma URL válida. Ou seja, o erro não tem nada a ver com o método HTTP (PUT) usado.

Comment: exatamente. Ja encontrei a solução amigo, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

PUT? Não recomendaria PUT porque não é suportado por todos os browsers. Você pode enviar por Ajax através de GET ou POST. Eu sempre uso GET ou POST e funciona bem.

> Documentation -
>   The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.>

Comment: para usar o restful, é necessário praticamente todos os métodos

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso possa resolver o seu problema:

No atributo type do JSON, você o define como POST e no seu formulário ou atributo data do JSON adiciona um campo como este:

`<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">`

O procedimento nesse caso é semelhante a uma requisição POST, diferindo apenas porque há a necessidade de adicionar um input do tipo hidden especificando o tipo de requisição, que no exemplo mostrado é PUT.

Comment: Ja encontrei a solução amigo, obrigado